# Error after adding bitmap resource from the command line?

Tags: android, command-line, android-resources

I'm developing for Android via emacs/command line and I have a simple question. I'd like to add a bitmap resource and create it as an `ImageView`. Creating the directory `res/drawable-ldpi` and adding a .png results in the error:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`

`ComponentInfo{org.example.Application1.MainActivity}:`

`android.content.res.ResourcesNotFoundException: File res/drawable-ldpi/pic.png from xml`

`type layout resource ID #0x...` {etc}

There were no errors during compilation. Running `ant debug` yields the following:

-snip-

`[echo]----------`

`[echo] Handling Resources...`

`[aapt] Found Deleted Target File`

`[aapt] Generating resource IDs...`

`[echo]----------`

-snip-

`-crunch:`

`[crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\DEV\Application1\res`

`[crunch] To destination dir: C:\DEV\Application1\bin\res`

`[crunch] Processing image to cache: C:\DEV\Application1\res\drawable-ldpi\pic.png => C:\DEV\Application1\bin\res\drawable-ldpi\pic.png`

`[crunch]    (processed image to cache entry C:\DEV\Application1\bin\res\drawable-ldpi\pic.png (87% size of source)`

`[crunch] Crunched 1 PNG file to update cache`

-snip-

Most of the Android help I've found involves Eclipse, which I'm not using and do not wish to use. Is there something further I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `drawable` was the directory to use, not `drawable-ldpi`.

If someone can explain why, I can mark that as an answer.